# Can the broth from a low country boil be used for anything else?

Tags: culinary-uses, seafood, broth

For those who might not know what a low country boil is; it's basically potatoes, corn, sausage, shrimp (and crab or lobster) boiled all together with seasonings (usually seafood boil packets, lemons, and old bay).

Most recipes I've seen have you just dump the "broth" into the sink.  Is it possible to save the broth and use it for anything else later?

Answer (score 8):

Your instincts are good; throwing tasty broth away is a criminal waste!  I have a couple ideas that are worth a shot.

1. **Risotto:** use it for the broth or stock. You may wish to add some more sausage and seasfood bits in for extra tastiness.
2. **Rice/pilaf:** use the broth in place of water for cooking the rice.  It'll give a richer flavor to the result.
3. **Bisque:**  Reduce broth, salt it, season, and mix with cream and maybe a little roux to thicken it.
4. **Pan sauce:** Throw broth in a saucepan, reduce it by up to half, and stir in cold roux to thicken, then season with salt, paprika, pepper, herbs (thyme, parsley, rosemary), and maybe a splash of white wine.  It should produce an excellent savory sauce, akin to a veloute.
5. **Bread:** Replace some or all of the water in bread you bake with the broth, to give the bread part of the flavor.  *Since I don't know how much of each ingredient the boil has, I can't say if this will come out tasty or not, but it's worth a shot.*

The other 4 items are pretty safe bets, as long as the broth is fairly tasty. If you reduce and thicken the broth with roux, cornstarch, cream, or cheese, you'll probably be able to turn it into something tasty to dip bread into. In a pinch, it could also become a soup.

One note: **you may wish to simmer the broth down until reduced by half** to get a stronger flavor for use in other dishes; however, taste it periodically to make sure it's not becoming too overpowering in flavor. **If the boil is already fully salted, you will need to adjust salt accordingly when using the broth in cooking.** Reduce salt in dishes prepared from it, avoid reducing down the broth to prevent it becoming too salty, and maybe even dilute it down with water.

Comment: +1 good answer. To *boil* the advice down, you've made broth, use it as such. ;o) The one thing to consider is that it may be a bit starchy from the potatoes and corn. Probably doesn't make a huge difference, but keep it in mind.

Comment: I can see you're really taken _stock_ of my answer.

Comment: @ yossarian - I usually boil the potatoes whole or cut into halves.  The corn is only boiled for the last 10 minutes (it usually goes in 4 or 5 minutes before crab legs, and about 7 minutes before the shrimp.  After the shrimp have boiled for 2-3 minutes, I kill the heat and drain the broth.

Comment: I'm glad that you guys were able to REDUCE the possibilities for me

Comment: +1 I don't know which I liked better, the excellent answer or the clever comments.

Comment: For #3 -- taste before you add more salt; most boils will have a fair amount of salt to start with.  I have no idea what's in the 'seafood boil packets', but old bay does have salt in it ([160mg per 1/4tsp](http://www.oldbay.com/products/old-bay-seasoning.aspx))

Comment: The starchiness in the broth will cause rice grains to clump. Personally I would not use this broth for pilaf or any Indian-style rice dish, where grains of rice are supposed to be separate rather than stick together. For steamed rice to accompany dishes from any cuisine where chopsticks are the tool of choice, the broth would work great.

Answer (score 2):

I make a bisque.  I scrape the corn from the cob and puree the vegis, add some whipping cream, and salt to taste after reducing your stock.  It is the best part of the meal.  If there are a lot of potatoes left I will use some in the bisque and then make some potato cakes to serve with the bisque.